# Oracle Stored Procedure not executing in .NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle

I am having a very rare problem witn Oracle and .NET, I have a simple select that retrieves a list of products, which works correctly. But then, with a stored procedure, it does not seem to execute it, yet it doesn't say anything about any errors or parameters missing. It works correctly when run in SQL Developer.

```
OracleCommand ora_cmd = new OracleCommand("a6r1.PR_ABC_P_ALTA_TARJETA_PAYWARE", ora_conn);
ora_cmd.BindByName = true;
ora_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

int exito = 0;

ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Param_Issuer", OracleDbType.Varchar2, issuer, ParameterDirection.Input);
ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Ln_Param_Valid_Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2, DropDownListProducto.SelectedValue.ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Ln_Param_Total", OracleDbType.Int32, Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxCantidad.Text) , ParameterDirection.Input);
ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Param_User", OracleDbType.Varchar2, user, ParameterDirection.Input);
ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Encrypted_Password", OracleDbType.Varchar2, pass, ParameterDirection.Input);
ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Exito", OracleDbType.Int32, exito, ParameterDirection.Output);
/*********************Oracle Command**********************************************************************/

ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

The SP is too large to place here, so I will only add the header.

```
PROCEDURE PR_ABC_P_ALTA_TARJETA_PAYWARE (
     Lc_Param_Issuer In Varchar2,
     Ln_Param_Valid_Product In Varchar2,
     Ln_Param_Total In Number,
     Lc_Param_User In Varchar2,
     Lc_Encrypted_Password In Varchar2,
     Lc_Exito Out Number
     )
```

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: You should indent your code better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    using Oracle.DataAccess;
    using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

    public DataTable ExecuteSP()
    {
        using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "PR_ABC_P_ALTA_TARJETA_PAYWARE";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.BindByName = true;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Param_Issuer", OracleDbType.Varchar2, issuer, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Ln_Param_Valid_Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2, DropDownListProducto.SelectedValue.ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Ln_Param_Total", OracleDbType.Int32, Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxCantidad.Text) , ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Param_User", OracleDbType.Varchar2, user, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Encrypted_Password", OracleDbType.Varchar2, pass, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Exito", OracleDbType.Int32, exito, ParameterDirection.Output);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("T_CURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, for the love of memory, wrap that `OracleDataAdapter` and `OracleCommand` in `using` statements.